# Can I take a screenshot on a windows machine that is running without a monitor?

Tags: python, winapi, rendering, screenshot, bitblt

I have a bank of virtual machines (running windows) that I remote into.  As such, none of these machines have a monitor attached, they are only accessed by Remote Desktop.

I want to get a screenshot of an application that is running on the desktop.  What I have found is that if I am not connected via Remote Desktop, then the screen is not rendering and I am unable capture the screen (the best I've managed is getting a black image).

Is there any way to force the desktop to render for the purpose of my screen grab?

EDIT:
OK to be more specific, here is some Python code that takes a screenshot provided I am remoted in to the machines:

```
import win32ui
import win32gui
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, window_name)
wDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
dcObj = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(wDC)
cDC=dcObj.CreateCompatibleDC()
dataBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
dataBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(dcObj, width, height)
cDC.SelectObject(dataBitMap)
cDC.BitBlt((0, 0), (width, height), dcObj, (0, 0), win32con.SRCCOPY)
dataBitMap.SaveBitmapFile(cDC, image_name)
# Free Resources
dcObj.DeleteDC()
cDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, wDC)
win32gui.DeleteObject(dataBitMap.GetHandle())
```

If I run this while I am remoted in, it works fine.  As soon as I am not remoted in, I get the following error:

> win32ui.error: BitBlt failed

This error is a result of the screen not being rendered when no one is remoted in.

I need a solution that will allow me to get a screenshot in this scenario, when I am not connected via remote desktop.

EDIT 2:
To be clear, the code is running on the VM itself.  But it is running when no-one is remoted in to the machine.

Comment: There's some chance the instructions here might help: http://superuser.com/questions/62051/is-there-a-way-to-fake-a-dual-second-monitor

Comment: This is incredibly off-topic and my knowledge of virtual machines is anything but great. But I would say you might want to look into a Remote Desktop Protocol implementation for these purposes.

Comment: What did I do that earned this question so many downvotes?  I would like to know for future reference...

Comment: I'm voting to re-open as I know the answer.

Comment: It's not clear if you're trying to obtain a screenshot with code running in the  VM on the same desktop, running in the same VM but on another desktop, or running outside the VM on the host.

Comment: This question seems fine to me.

Comment: Ross, I'm running the code on the VM itself, but doing so while I'm not remoted in.  I will update the question to make this absolutely clear.

Comment: Joshua - The question is open now, I would greatly appreciate it if you put the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obvious workaround is using 2 virtual machines: master host runs remote session for target one. It also allows input actions like `mouse_event` or `keybd_event`. The only one requirement is not to minimize RDP window (or VNC software, it's doesn't matter), though it may be out of focus.

It's widely used method for build/test machines pool. I worked in big testing team several years and never heard about other approaches.

P.S. How about [Pillow](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0) or [pyscreenshot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyscreenshot)?

Comment: It's an interesting idea.  Ideally I'd like to be able to screenshot without being remoted in at all.  If I went this route I'd need to be able to automate a one VM establishing a remote desktop connection to all the others, and making sure it maintains the connection (catering for disconnects, rebooots, other users remoting in, etc.), which would be tricky.

Comment: I've marked this as correct as, ultimately, this is pretty much what we did to solve the problem.  Thanks for the response.